# Best way to retrieve data in getView?

Tags: android, listviewitem, custom-adapter

I'm using a custom adapter for my `ListView` and I have large amount of data suppose to be showing in the list, I have an holder pattern but I'm using `holder.textview.setText(getItem(position))` in the getView method to retrieve data. Is it good idea to use `getItem` for large amount of data or it's better to use direct code `holder.textview.setText(citiesList.get(position).getName())` ?

My getItem Method is :

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return citiesList.get(position).getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best of using getItem but also just doing it once, not once for each holder item.

```
YourObject obj = getItem(position);
holder.textview.setText(obj.getName());
holder.textview2.setText(obj.getSomethingElse());
```

using `getItem` mean's you can change the implementation of the backing collection and change less code if this happens. i.e. swapping from being backed with an ArrayList to a Cursor. You would only have to change it in one place (inside `getItem`) rather than all through the `getView` method which is kind of less obvious.